# Что такое блок трансляции?

Tags: c++, терминология

В самоучителе по C++ столкнулся с термином **блок трансляции** (в разделе в котором написано про **using** директиву), подскажите что это может быть?

Comment: Не помешала бы ссылка на книгу: издание, автор, номер страницы. А ещё лучше, привести цитату дословно.

Comment: освой самостоятельно С++ за 21 день. Джесс Либерти, Бредли Джонс. страница 559

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Перед компиляцией по вашим исходникам проходится препроцессор и создает один или несколько текстовых файлов, которые собственно и будут преобразованы компилятором в obj файлы. Каждый из таких файлов и является блоком трансляции. В каждый из них попадает как минимум один из файлов исходного кода, "корневой", и все включенные в него файлы.